# Flask application showing 404

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-404

I am new to Python and Flask and I need to work on a code base. I have the following files in directory called `migration`

```
Name

app
env
__pycache__
requirements.txt
run.py
```

In the `run.py`, I have a the following code:

```
from app import app

app.run(debug=True)
```

and inside the `app` directory, I have one `__init__.py`, which as code :

```
from app.helpers import get_page_display_name, get_page_url_name
# from app import views
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False
app.jinja_env.globals.update(get_page_display_name=get_page_display_name)
app.jinja_env.globals.update(get_page_url_name=get_page_url_name)
```

Now I have a `views.py` file inside the same `app` folder and it has the route configuration and corresponding code like :

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    if 'username' in session:
        return render_template("index.html")
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

I am trying to run the application. I have used the following commands:

`env/Scripts/activate`

This has activated the environment and then:

```
$env:FLASK_APP=.\run.py
flask run
```

This has shown a message like it is running on `http://127.0.0.1:5000` and printed the following messages when I opened the URL in browser:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Nov/2020 10:23:15] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Nov/2020 10:23:15] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Nov/2020 10:23:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Nov/2020 10:23:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Nov/2020 10:23:18] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Nov/2020 10:23:18] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Nov/2020 10:23:18] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I have also tried with

```
$env:FLASK_APP=.\app\views.py
flask run
```

This also has printed the same message as it is running on the same port, but when opened, the same 404 messages are being shown.

How can I run this application ? I have checked the documentation, but the structure is little different for this application. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import your views file after definition of `app`. I suggest you to use `blueprint`.

## EDIT

`views.py`

```
from flask import Blueprint

bp = Blueprint('test', __name__, url_prefix='/')

@bp.route('/')
def index():
    if 'username' in session:
        return render_template("index.html")
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

`__init__py`

```
from app.helpers import get_page_display_name, get_page_url_name
from views import bp
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(bp)
app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False
app.jinja_env.globals.update(get_page_display_name=get_page_display_name)
app.jinja_env.globals.update(get_page_url_name=get_page_url_name)
```

Comment: Thanks Heydar. But can you please show me how ? I am actually looking into the blueprints, but need to get this app working to know various functionalities.